# developing plugin for eclipse

Tags: pointers, eclipse-plugin

Anybody out there who had developed plugins for eclipse?
I am using eclipse for last 4-5 years and am just thinking about developing some plugins for eclipse. I dont know anything about that, like how its written and all. If someone who has experience on this can show light over that, it would be great. Some really good tutorials or links or any useful articles will do.

Cheers,
PK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this might help you have a look
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

and for breif you can go here too
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecplug/

Answer (score 4):

Here is one more tutorial: http://eclipsepluginsite.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can start from creating a sample eclipse plugin project. You could also use their plugin-spy (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>) to gain insight into any screen. You can start from [your first plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at the sample code that is generated by creating a new project using the various plug-in wizards.